# is this a Sql query or linq

Tags: sql, asp.net

any one know what kind of query is this??

```
var r = dc.user_details.Where(a => a.username.Equals(u.username) && a.passkey.Equals(u.passkey)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This definitely is _not_ SQL, but it could be a framework like Linq.

Comment: It's LINQ , check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is LINQ query. (The Enumerable methods are part of system.linq namespace)

The method "where" is part of "Enumerable Methods".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Inside "Where" the predicate is a **lamda expression.** (This is a C# programming concept. Not part of LINQ)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Again the "FirstOrDefault" is a "Enumerable method", You can find it in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

These are an extension methods that achieves the same as LINQ. It is another way for writing LINQ queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is a linq query which checks the username and passkey and gives the result weather the user name and passkey exist in the table or not.